# How to show $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin({\frac{1}{x}})dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

How to show $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin({\frac{1}{x}})dx$ converges?

I have that $$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x}}\le \frac{\sin({\frac{1}{x}})}{\sqrt{x}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$ but when you integrate you get

$$-\infty \le \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin({\frac{1}{x}})dx \le \infty$$

Is there another function you could bound it by to show convergence at $\infty$?

Comment: It's not enough that $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded for large $x$; you need it to go to zero (and fairly quickly) for the integral to converge.

Comment: Yes there is and it's fairly similar to your approach. Just note that $\sin(x)\leq x$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Define $f(x):= \frac{  \sin(1/x) } { \sqrt x} $.

- If $0\lt x \lt 1$, then $|f(x)|\leqslant 1/\sqrt x$ and $\int_0^1 1/\sqrt x\mathrm dx$ is convergent.
- If $x\gt 1$, due to the inequality $|\sin t|\leqslant |t|$ for any $t$, we have $|f(x)|\leqslant 1/x^{3/2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one doubt and please help me. $|f(x)|\leqslant 1/\sqrt x$ taken only for $0\lt x \lt 1$. Does it hold for $x>1$? Also does $|\sin t|\leqslant |t|$ hold for $0\lt x \lt 1$?

Comment: The inequality you mention are true for all positive $t$, $x$, but not always useful.